# If $A^2=0$ then $J^2=0$ - Jordan Form

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If $A$ over the field $\Bbb C$ and $A^2=0$, we can say that $A$ is similar to a jordan form. Does this mean we are able to say that:

$$J^2=0$$ aswell, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. $A$ being similar to $J$ means that $J=SAS^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $S$. Therefore $J^2=(SAS^{-1})^2 = SAS^{-1}SAS^{-1} = SA^2S^{-1}= S0S^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: Of course, thank you!